# Get description of a built-in method/function or property, by reflection, or otherwise, in Javascript, particularly node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to get the description of what a built-in method/function or property does/means by reflection in node.js?

Like if there's a function getDescription(), such that:

```
let desc = getDescription(Array.prototype.at) // is a string
console.log(desc)
```

It will output something like:

```
Takes an integer value and returns the item at that index, allowing for positive and negative integers. Negative integers count back from the last item in the array.
```

(this is the description given on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

I'd like to compile a csv of all the built-in objects, methods and properties, together with their descriptions, and upload it into a site liked quizlet.com to make flash cards for learning, and/or turn it into a quiz for self-assessment (each question in the quiz will show the description, and I'd have to give the property/method/object it describes as the answer.)

I am trying to avoid retrieving the documentation pages by http from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference. I have adopted this approach for PHP before, and found it really tedious to map the property/method/object name to the relevant document page URL, and then still have to parse the HTML from the documentation page to retrieve the description.

Preferably any suggestion can be extended to any runtime environment, especially browser-side Javascript, Google Apps Script..

Comment: This seems very complex for little gain. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The Nodejs runtime does not contain a copy of the MDN documentation, and it does not offer any other reflection capabilities either.

You will have a much better experience "scraping" [their git repository](https://github.com/mdn/content/tree/main/files) which also contains machine-readable data. That said, an alternative might be the [TypeScript declaration files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/src/lib) that also contain short descriptions for most functions and their overloads, and is definitely machine-readable.